# How to decrypt access_token inside a .net core app

Tags: .net-core, access-token

The authentication server is a .net framework app which generates a token using the machineKey here is the snipet

```
    public async Task GrantResourceOwnerCredentials(OAuthGrantResourceOwnerCredentialsContext context)
{

        var userAuthResult = Authentication.AuthenticateUser(context.UserName, context.Password, ref userId);
        if (userAuthResult != AuthenticateUserResult.Success)
        {
            context.SetError("invalid_grant", "Unable to Authorize");
            return;
        }

    var claims = new List<Claim>
    {
        new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, UserName),
        new Claim("DisplayName", FirstName),
    };

    var oAuthIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, context.Options.AuthenticationType);         

    AuthenticationProperties properties = CreateProperties(context.ClientId);
    var ticket = new AuthenticationTicket(oAuthIdentity, properties);
    context.Validated(ticket);
}
```

There is another .net core application (API) which I working on right now. The user passes the access_token which gets from authentication server via authorization header.  What I am trying to do is look for a way to decrypt the token to see the claims. I was wondering if there is a library which I can pass in the token and machineKey to decrypt it or any other way?

Comment: The closest solution I have got is this one https://long2know.com/2015/05/decrypting-owin-authentication-ticket/  but it is still not for .net core.